# JavaScript jQuery Variables i should avoid using that conflicts with Global variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, global-variables

What are JavaScript/jQuery variable names i should avoid creating that could conflict with already existing Global variables. Yesterday i discovered that i cannot use the variable `default`. It must be a global variable.

Comment: Do you have to use globals at all? Just create a new top scope by putting all your code in an immediate function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`default` is not a global variable: it is a reserved word (it's used in `switch` statements).

You can find a list of reserved keywords [on the MDC website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words).

Note also that there are various other names that you should be careful with. For instance, a variable named `location` could conflict with the `window.location` object unless you're careful.  For this reason (among others), you should avoid global variables.

Other such variables are:

- `window.top`
- `window.parent`
- `window.document`
- `window.self`
- and quite a few more.

Answer (score 3):

default is one of the JavaScript [reserved words](http://www.quackit.com/javascript/javascript_reserved_words.cfm) (which is also the list of variables to avoid using). jQuery wise it is $ although you can use jQuery in [no conflict mode](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/).

Answer (score 2):

default is a JavaScript keyword:

```
switch(foo)
{
    case a:
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

As for jQuery reserved words, [check out this link](http://jqfundamentals.com/book/index.html) (scroll down to the "Reserved Words" section)

Answer (score 2):

These are JavaScript's reserved words:

- abstract
- boolean, break, byte
- case, catch, char, class, const, continue
- debugger, default, delete, do, double
- else, enum, export, extends
- false, final, finally, float, for, function
- goto
- if, implements, import, in, instanceof, int, interface
- long
- native, new, null
- package, private, protected, public
- return
- short, static, super, switch, synchronized
- this, throw, throws, transient, true, try, typeof
- var, volatile, void
- while, with

You should avoid naming you variables the same as that list.

I hope this helps.
Hristo

Answer (score 1):

`default` is not a global variable, it's a [reserved word](http://javascript.about.com/library/blreserved.htm) in JavaScript.

If you are going to use global variables, you should [namespace them](http://blogger.ziesemer.com/2007/10/respecting-javascript-global-namespace.html).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at:

http://jqfundamentals.com/book/index.html

There's a special content of reserved words.

Answer (score 1):

when building jQuery plugins, be aware that $.fn.init = function() could lead to problems and you should rather use another name for your function.
http://www.sarahleeashraf.com/explaining-jquery-part-2-init-function